# .Net Core Blazor How to pass multiple parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Click the a TAB to pass multiple parameters. How to receive

```
<a href="../navigatetopage?id="1"&key="img"></a>
```

In the page you want to navigate to, add the parameter to your route:

```
@page "/navigatetopage/"

[Parameter]
private string myvalue{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Route parameters instead of QueryString:

```
@page "/navigatetopage/{id:int}/{key}"

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id{get;set;}
    [Parameter] public string Key{get;set;}

    ...
}
```

And the url looks like:

```
<a href="../navigatetopage/1/img"></a>
```

Or if you do want to query string, set the property/field within `OnParametersSet()`:

```
@page "/navigatetopage/"

@code {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Key{get;set;}

    protected override void OnParametersSet(){
        var qs= navManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navManager.Uri).Query;
        var query = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(qs);
        if (query.TryGetValue("id", out var id_str)) {
            if (Int32.TryParse(id_str, out var id)){
                this.Id = id;
            }
        }
        if (query.TryGetValue("Key", out var key)) {
            this.Key = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this be achieved in the same way with 2 separate GUIDs?

Comment: @itminus With the query string approach, OnParametersSet() is _not_ invoked when we navigate within the same page (i.e. only update the query string), correct?

Answer (score 5):

A very simple solution to pass several parameters to a page is to use **[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "myParam")]**

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "id")]
    public int myId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Key")]
    public String myKey { get; set; }
}
```

and it is then useless to change the routing @page "navigatetopage".

We can also write `/navigatetopage?id=1&key=img`

Answer (score 4):

Using Blazor Server I wanted to be able to pass multiple route parameters using `NavigateTo`. It took me way longer than it should have to get an answer that worked for me so I thought I would share:

On the component I want to navigate to:

```
@page "/nextpage/caseId/{caseId:int}/showSecrets/{showSecrets:bool}
```

On the component, I want to navigate from after injecting `NavigationManager` nav:

```
int caseID = 17;  //for example <br>
nav.NavigateTo("nextpage/caseId/" + caseId +"/showSecrets/" + true);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is 3 years old but I feel this might help.

What you are looking for is passing multiple parameters using (Query strings)
Microsoft has a great explanation of it here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#query-strings

I believe this will solve the issue:

```
@page "/navigatetopage/"

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
private string id{ get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
private string key{ get; set; }
```

Note: I believe you use `[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "myParam")]`
only when your parameters are named differently than the Query parameters, or you have something like an array and you want to fill it from the Query